# devbridge autocomplete suddenly throwing error

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using devbridge's autocomplete, which was working but suddenly now is not. It's throwing an error:

EDITED

I made a test page. The error being thrown is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var options, a;
            jQuery(function(){
                options = { serviceUrl:'php/getNations.php' };
                a = $('#countryofOrigin').autocomplete(options);
            }); 
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="countryofOrigin" name="countryofOrigin" placeholder="COUNTRY OF ORIGIN" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect that there might be a conflict with jquery ui autocomplete. Did you just include it recently?

Comment: @Tomas Kirda: Thanks so much for answering! I took out the jquery ui include, but the error is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. There were two problems:

1 - I had a link to the wrong php page.

2 - There was a conflict with http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js.